# Проблема запуска jar с log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j

Собираю при помощи maven проект в jar файл. Если отключить логирование то все ок, но с логированием jar при запуске выдает

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

Пример конфига log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, toFile
log4j.appender.toFile = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.toFile.File = target/logs/test.log
log4j.appender.toFile.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.toFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toFile.layout.ConversionPattern= %d %5p [%t] - %c.%M %L - %m%n
```

Зависимости

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ua.dnepr.timefinder.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Есть предположения с чем связано? Есть предположение что в jar не добавился пакет с самим log4j

Comment: Приведите список зависимостей, подключенных к проекту, пожалуйста

Comment: Привел в вопросе.

Comment: Под debug работает нормально? А когда запускаете - получаете ошибку? Если да, то покажите ещё раздел `build` в вашем `pom.xml`

Comment: в IDE работает, когда запускаю JAR то ошибка. Сеичас посмотрел в jar нету библиотеки log4j, но как не пытаюсь не могу туда добавить

Comment: Добавил ответ. Пробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в раздел build следующий plugin

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

этот плагин "запакует" всё в Ваш JAR файл.

Называтся он будет

> *-shaded.jar.

Его и используйте

Comment: Работает, но я бы хотел понять что там происходит:)

Comment: Если по простому - то все зависимости в виде классов упаковываются в ваш JAR. А вообще вам необходимо изучить работу данного плагина, если хотите углубленно разобраться. К примеру https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ и http://study-and-dev.com/blog/build_management_maven_8/

Comment: Chubatiy ответил совершено правильно. Вообще, существует множество инструментов для логгирования в Java (например log4j) тут есть хорошая статья http://devify.ru/p/logging-in-spring-boot про их сравнение и конфигурацию.